# "Ignoring unavailable cipher suite" attaching to RSA Auth Manager

Tags: authentication, ssl, encryption

Here is the code, in its entirety:

```
public class connect {
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        com.rsa.authagent.authapi.AuthSessionFactory.getInstance(null);
    }
}
```

I run it with debug turned on and I get:

```
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: SERIALNUMBER=eab48e9c64457b5c09b033691cb81426d1315b853b83bd47eee5d9f40a5dcb4a, CN=RSA root CA for den-prod-rsa02.ch.int
  Issuer:  SERIALNUMBER=eab48e9c64457b5c09b033691cb81426d1315b853b83bd47eee5d9f40a5dcb4a, CN=RSA root CA for den-prod-rsa02.ch.int
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x27d0015b935d1919b03b41b4e2aa42bf
  Valid from Thu Oct 16 03:41:08 PDT 2014 until Wed Dec 31 16:00:00 PST 2036
```

*[ above repeated two more times ]*

```
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Using SSLEngineImpl.
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
```

*[ ten more cipher suites ignored ]*

```
Exception in thread "main" com.rsa.authagent.authapi.AuthAgentException: com.rsa.authagent.authapi.AuthAgentException: Error in initial AuthnReq/Rsp for serverTime.Error in processing Authn request: Cannot support TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA with currently installed providers
    at com.rsa.authagent.authapi.AuthSessionFactory.a(AuthSessionFactory.java)
    at com.rsa.authagent.authapi.AuthSessionFactory.getInstance(AuthSessionFactory.java)
    at connect.main(connect.java:5)
```

The server is "right" in the sense that it's a production server that hundreds of people use every day.  The client is pretty minimal (and drawn from the RSA examples).  So that leaves my computer: I have to tweak the configuration in some way.

The only recommendations I have found are

- install the unlimited-strength US-only encryption libraries (already done)
- download the cert from the the server and install it with keytool in the `$JAVA_HOME//lib/security` directory (tried that, and except for apparently causing an intermittent 45-second pause, it had no apparent effect).

Comment: I don't what parts (and log and error messages) are from the server and what are from the client in this question. These messages are what I'd expect from an SSL server that has been misconfigured without a keystore.

Comment: @GregS -- I have no access to the server (except through the API); the logs are all from the client.  Yes, all the references I could find suggested exactly what you are saying, that the server lacks a keystore, but this server *works for everyone else*.  It even works for the same code running on a different computer.  Could it be a firewall issue?

Comment: As far as I know those messages will only occur when the ciphersuite cannot *possibly* be used. On a server (that is, the server side of SSL/TLS) that can happen when the server doesn't have a private key available to it in its keystore. On the client or server, I suppose that can happen if you don't have the unlimited strength crypto config jars installed. Are there messages about AES_128 ciphers being ignored? If not then I bet you installed the unlimited crypto config files in the wrong place.

Comment: What would be the right place?